# Why doesn't my model show up in QListView?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qlistview, qabstractitemmodel

I am trying to get a simple QAbstractItemModel to show up in a QListView but am struggling a bit. Here is my model implementation:

```
TestModel::TestModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractItemModel(parent)
{
}

QVariant TestModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return QVariant("FRED");
    }

    return QVariant();
}

Qt::ItemFlags TestModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return Qt::ItemIsSelectable |  Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
}

QVariant TestModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return QVariant("BING");
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QModelIndex TestModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return createIndex(row, column);
}

QModelIndex TestModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return createIndex(0, 0);
}

int TestModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 1;
}

int TestModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 1;
}
```

If I set the model of my QListView to an instance of the above model then nothing shows up. However, if I use a QTableView instead then it is populated as expected.

What do I need to do to get this simple example to work with a QListView?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: I don't know if this is causing the problem, but for indexes that don't have a parent, `parent()` should return an invalid `QModelIndex` (created with the default constructor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List model has no parent hierarchy.
Hence, `parent` method shall be implemented as,

```
QModelIndex TestModel::parent(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QModelIndex();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was indeed the problem.